# Singleton archiving not unarchiving usable instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've run into some trouble trying to archive my singleton for my project. Technically this applies to two singletons that I archive under a single wrapper array but for the purposes of this question, I'll only involve the "Notebook" singleton.

My problem is that recalling this archive doesn't reproduce the instance correctly, everything appears to be "null" but the app otherwise performs.

My idea is to archive the singleton once the app enters the background, so here's that method in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

Settings *sharedSettings = [Settings sharedSettings];
Notebook *sharedNotebook = [Notebook sharedNotebook];
NSArray *array_wrapperForSave = @[sharedSettings, sharedNotebook];

NSArray *archiveDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *archivePathForArray = [archiveDirectory objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *directoryForArray = [archivePathForArray stringByAppendingString:@"UserDataBundle.archive"];
archivePath = directoryForArray;

BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array_wrapperForSave toFile:archivePath];

NSLog(@"Data Archive Status: %d", success);
```

That NSLog returns 1 (success)

Here is Notebook.m's initializer(s), the important offending line is that last method call:

```
#pragma mark - Initializers

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        array_highlights = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        array_sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        sharedSettings = [Settings sharedSettings];
        indexOfLastLoadedSection = 0;

        Section *rootSection = [[Section alloc] initWithTitle:@"Main Tab"];
        [self saveSection:rootSection];

//        self = [self accessArchivedInstance];     // This causes some huge issues.
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        array_sections = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array_sections"];
        array_highlights = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array_highlights"];
        indexOfLastLoadedSection = [aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"indexOfLastLoadedSection"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here is that method which grabs the file path to the wrapper array and uncases the proper object instance at the index:

```
- (Notebook *)accessArchivedInstance {
    NSArray *archiveDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *archivePathForArray = [archiveDirectory objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *directoryForArray = [archivePathForArray stringByAppendingString:@"UserDataBundle.archive"];


    NSArray *array_archivedSingletons = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:directoryForArray];
    Notebook *returnInstance = [array_archivedSingletons objectAtIndex:1];

    NSLog(@"Notebook Instance awaking from Archive");

    return returnInstance;
}
```

Singleton method:

```
+ (id)sharedNotebook {
    static Notebook *sharedNotebook = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedNotebook = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedNotebook;
}
```

I can of course provide any extra info if needed. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the code for `Notebook sharedInstance`. Also show what you do with the return value from the `accessArchivedInstance` method. I suspect the problem is those two are not tied together.

Comment: You have a serious bug in how you build your archive path. Change `NSString *directoryForArray = [archivePathForArray stringByAppendingString:@"UserDataBundle.archive"];` to `NSString *directoryForArray = [archivePathForArray stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserDataBundle.archive"];`. Fix that in both places.

Comment: @rmaddy I fixed the stringByAppendingString and while it didn't solve the problem completely, I'm sure that puts me a step closer. Also, `accessArchivedInstance` is supposed to return the saved instance of Notebook and I use that method to set self to that saved instance in the init.  Singleton method has been added to question body.

Comment: You still haven't shown how you use the result of the call to `accessArchivedInstance`. Your problem is likely that the call to `Notebook sharedNotebook` returns the local static variable `sharedNotebook` and the call to `accessArchivedInstance` can't ever set that variable. So you have two completely separate `Notebook` instances.

Comment: Sorry, I may be misunderstanding. I use `accessArchivedInstance` to set self to the return value for that method, which should be my saved singleton instance. `self = [self accessArchivedInstance];` As for your second point, I'm pretty new to archiving/unarchiving, could you explain what you think I should do in terms of that double instance issue? I always thought it was impossible with the dispatch once singleton method to give two instances of Notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you never really use `accessArchiveInstance` and when you tried it was in the wrong place.

Modify `sharedNotebook` to be:

```
+ (id)sharedNotebook {
    static Notebook *sharedNotebook = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSArray *archiveDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *archivePathForArray = [archiveDirectory objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *directoryForArray = [archivePathForArray stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserDataBundle.archive"];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:directoryForArray]) {
            NSArray *array_archivedSingletons = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:directoryForArray];
            sharedNotebook = [array_archivedSingletons objectAtIndex:1];
        } else {
            sharedNotebook = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    });

    return sharedNotebook;
}
```

And remove the `accessArchiveInstance` method.

Comment: One other suggestion. Don't put both singletons in the same archive file. Read and write each one from its own file. It's inefficient to have to read both objects from the same file twice when each time you only want one of the objects. And what happens down the road when you get rid of one singleton or add another? Suddenly, this method doesn't know which array index to access. If you really want a single file, at least change to a dictionary instead of an array. Then you can access the proper object by key and not worry about changing indexes over time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll change that and figure out how to add multiple archives.